# Firebase: Rewriting with URL segments to custom html files

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have the following lines in my firebase.json file:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/blog/abc",
    "destination": "/abc.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "/blog/def",
    "destination": "/def.html"
  },
  ......
  ......
]
```

How can I make it into single statement similar to this:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/blog/:post*",
    "destination": "/:post.html"
  }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a reference for path segment globbing and capture with firebase cloud functions as opposed to rewriting to html file but, from testing it seems to be unavailable.

Simple / hack solution for your restful urls if you really need path segment globbing and capture in your firebase cloud functions:

```
    function pathSegmantVars(request, pathName, checkForQuery = true, queryName = undefined){
      // support separate path vs query string var names
      const query = queryName ? queryName : pathName
    
      // If requested, use the query var if it exists
      if(checkForQuery && request.query[query]) {
        return request.query[query]
      }
    
      // Else check the path for the pathName variable
      const path = request.path
      const paths = path.split("/")
    
      if(paths.indexOf(pathName) && paths[paths.indexOf(pathName) + 1]){
        return paths[paths.indexOf(pathName) + 1]
      }
    
      throw new Error('Bad ' + query);
    }
```

and set up in firebase.json be all like:

```
"rewrites": [
 { "source": "/project/:projectId/assets", "function": "getProjectAssets" },
]
```

then call it like:

```
    const projectId = pathSegmantVars(request, 'project');
```

Note the :projectId segment name is not resolved in the cloud function, pathSegmantVars is matching on the previous path segment (eg "project").

And then change from `curl foo.com/assets?project=1234` to `curl foo.com/project/1234/assets`

If anyone knows how to get path segment globbing with capture in firebase without this hack I am all ears. Or Google, can I has cloud fn glob capture pls?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the [documentation on rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), you have the ability to glob/wildcard on the source path, but you can't capture and use that globbed string in the destination.  So it doesn't look possible.

Comment: This is correct, but you may want to look at the `cleanURLs` option which will serve content without the `.html` extension ([see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#control_html_extensions)).